# Want to cancel my return flight with Wizzair. Is it worth to bother?

Tags: cancellations, wizz-air

I want to cancel my return flight for 2 people with Wizzair 1 month before the flight(no insurance). I have 2 flights to Italy and 2 back from Italy. Is it worth it or the fee is gonna be too high?

On their website it says 60euro if you cancel up to 14 days. But on internet people say it's 60 per person per flight. Is that true?

For some reason I can't call their call centre from my country, it says that number does not exist.

Comment: Note that Wizzair has [several call centers for different countries](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us#/) listed on their website;  you may be able to find a number that works from your country there.

Comment: Something is better than nothing. Atleast you will get back a portion of the money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several sites seem to agree with what you have read, that the cancellation fee is per flight, not per booking. Which would mean 240 euro for your 4 flights. For example a flight refund site says:

> According to the website, a flight can be cancelled up to 14 days
>   before departure, but cancellation fees of 60 euros per person and
>   flight will be charged.

[Source](https://www.geld-fuer-flug.de/en/flight-cancellation/wizzair)

Where as you mentioned, the official website just states cancellation costs 60 euro.

If you have paid more than the cost to cancel, then it makes sense to get at least some money back, but if your flights have cost less than this, it would not be worth it.

They have different call centers for every country, which can be found [here](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us#faq-how-can-i-contact-the-wizz-air-call-centre). It seems calling up would be your only guaranteed way of finding out the cost.